# How to dynamically Change appsettings.json Based on Build Configuration in .NET

Tags: .net, msbuild, cicd, appsettings

I'm working on a .NET application and I'm facing a challenge with managing different environments (e.g., development, staging, production). I want to dynamically modify my appsettings.json file based on the build configuration, so that each deployment environment uses its specific connection strings among other settings.

Currently, I have separate appsettings.json files (like appsettings.Development.json, appsettings.Staging.json, etc.), but I'm looking for a more streamlined approach to automatically select the right settings without manually changing them before each build/deployment.

I looked into using MSBuild conditions within the .csproj file to copy specific appsettings files based on the configuration, but it seems cumbersome and error-prone.
I also considered environment variables, but I would prefer a solution that allows keeping all configurations within the project for simplicity.

Sometimes, during the build process (especially when not doing a full rebuild), it seems like the changes in the appsettings.json files do not get properly applied. For example, I could be deploying with the Production configuration, but the application still mistakenly uses settings from appsettings.Testing.json. This inconsistency is a significant concern, particularly when dealing with database connection strings.
Since Im deploying directly with Gitlab CI/CD i need to ensure the build fully rebuilds and accepts the appsettings always

Iam using .net 6.0

Comment: Why don't you just have one appsettings.json and transform variables on deployment ?

Comment: @J.Memisevic the app is getting big and some configurations have completely different appsettings structure I need to use different appsettings and swap them on build

Comment: @jakubpodhaisky with the `appsettings.environment.json` files that you have, you can automate selecting the correct file in MSBuild. You said it is "cumbersome and error-prone" but you didn't elaborate. Are you building for the `Debug` or `Release` Configuration and supporting a separate 'publish' step for the environment? The copying (or creating) of the environment specific `appsettings.json` file should be part of the publish step, not the build. (i.e. it should be possible to build and then publish that same build to multiple environments.)

Comment: @JonathanDodds, thank you for your suggestion. I must admit, my primary challenge has been the complexity and my own confusion around configuring MSBuild for environment-specific appsettings.json files. Despite my efforts, I wasn't able to set it up correctly to switch between appsettings.debug.json and appsettings.release.json based on the build configuration in Visual Studio. Ideally, when I select the Debug configuration, it should use appsettings.debug.json, and similarly, appsettings.release.json should be used when the Release configuration is selected.